# filter dplyr sqlite3 connection using regex

Tags: regex, r, sqlite, dplyr

I want to select rows from an sqlite3 connection through dplyr using a regular expression, unfortunately this doesn't seem possible. Is there a work around to filtering these rows based on a regex? Code below shows the error.

```
library(nycflights13)
my_db <- src_sqlite("my_db.sqlite3", create = T)
flights_sqlite <- copy_to(my_db, flights, temporary = FALSE, indexes = list(c("year", "month", "day"), "carrier", "tailnum"))
flights_sqlite <- tbl(nycflights13_sqlite(), "flights")
filter(flights_sqlite, grepl("N9.*", tailnum))

#> Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) :
#> error in statement: no such function: GREPL
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, `dplyr` can't translate many useful functions into the sql query it passes on to sqlite. You can see the list of functions it can in the [dplyr database vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html):

> dplyr knows how to convert the following R functions to SQL:
>
> - basic math operators: +, -, *, /, %%, ^
> - math functions: abs, acos,    acosh, asin, asinh, atan, atan2, atanh, ceiling, cos, cosh, cot,    coth, exp, floor, log, log10,
>     round, sign, sin, sinh, sqrt, tan, tanh
> - logical comparisons: <, <=, !=, >=, >, ==, %in%
> - boolean operations:    &, &&, |, ||, !, xor
> - basic aggregations: mean, sum, min, max, sd, var

However, `dplyr` will leave alone anything it can't translate and pass it to sqlite. This is where your error comes from - `dplyr` can't translate `grepl`, and so passes it to sqlite which throws the error.

If you know a little sql, you can write your own equivalent query, using `%like%`:

```
filter(flights_sqlite, tailnum %like% "N9%")

Source: sqlite 3.8.6 
From: flights [30,216 x 16]
Filter: tailnum %like% "N9%" 

    year month   day dep_time dep_delay arr_time arr_delay carrier tailnum flight origin  dest air_time
   (int) (int) (int)    (int)     (dbl)    (int)     (dbl)   (chr)   (chr)  (int)  (chr) (chr)    (dbl)
1   2013     1     1      602        -8      812        -8      DL  N971DL   1919    LGA   MSP      170
2   2013     1     1      608         8      807        32      MQ  N9EAMQ   3768    EWR   ORD      139
3   2013     1     1      655        -5     1002       -18      DL  N997DL   2003    LGA   MIA      161
4   2013     1     1      659        -6      907        -6      DL  N998DL    831    LGA   DTW      105
5   2013     1     1      717        -3      850        10      FL  N978AT    850    LGA   MKE      134
6   2013     1     1      754        -5     1039        -2      DL  N935DL   2047    LGA   ATL      126
7   2013     1     1      759        -1     1057       -30      DL  N955DL   1843    JFK   MIA      158
8   2013     1     1      804        -6     1103       -13      DL  N947DL   1959    JFK   MCO      147
9   2013     1     1      810         0     1048        11      9E  N915XJ   3538    JFK   MSP      189
10  2013     1     1      814         4     1047        17      FL  N977AT    346    LGA   ATL      132
..   ...   ...   ...      ...       ...      ...       ...     ...     ...    ...    ...   ...      ...
```